# Neo4j - One big transaction vs many small

Tags: java, neo4j, transactions

I am building the backend of an application that uses neo4j. I am using the native java API and currently for each client request I create one transaction and inside this transaction I am submitting three different traversals and query the graph for multiple nodes and relationships to get the results I want. My question is wether it's better to have one big transaction of to create one transaction per neo4j access.

Comment: if you're not updating the graph, there's no need for a transaction, right?

Comment: Sounds a bit like your access read-only, meaning you may not need a transactions at all. The benefit of larger transactions comes from the ability to write more changes in one go. It depends on what bottlenecks you, the write-speed-limit of your disk or the CPU? It's very unlikely that CPU bound limits go away with a different transaction strategy while IO bound limits can, but aren't guaranteed to be affected.

Comment: Even read only operation need transactions.

Comment: Oops, ok, neo4j is designed so that you have to do them explicitly. However in case of read-only access they most importantly alter consistency guarantees ([transaction-isolation](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#transactions-isolation)), they shouldn't have much effect on performance. That is most relevant for write access. However, what Jordi Castilla said is true, you have to profile the options if you want to know if one is better then the other.